# Debug support for multithread node.js javascript in vs code

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, visual-studio-code

Is there any support for debugging of a JavaScript with multiple threads running on Node.js in vs code?

Comment: Have you tried it? What issues did you face?

Comment: I tried with a breakpoint in the worker but it did not break.